# Utilising Shiny's progress bar with leaflet cluster plugin

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

[**Leaflet's markercluster plugin**](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) offers `chunkProgress` callback function that provides information on the loading of data points, I would like to incorporate information from that function in [**Shiny's progress indicator**](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html) displaying information on the number of loaded data points.

## Sample app

*The app code draws on official examples made available by at [**Leaflet for R**](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html) and [**Shiny's**](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html) pages.*

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

r_colors <- rgb(t(col2rgb(colors()) / 255))
names(r_colors) <- colors()
noMarkers <- 200

ui <- fluidPage(leafletOutput("mymap"),
                p(),
                actionButton("recalc", "New points"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    points <- eventReactive(input$recalc, {
        cbind(rnorm(noMarkers) * 2 + 13, rnorm(noMarkers) + 48)
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

    output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
        withProgress(message = 'Making plot', value = 0, {

            # How can I replace noMarkers with dynamic values 
            # passed from the callback function
            incProgress(1 / noMarkers, detail = paste("Doing point", noMarkers))

            leaflet() %>%
                addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
                                 options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
                addMarkers(data = points(),
                           clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
        })
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## Problem

According to the information available through [marker cluster pages](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster):

> `chunkProgress`: Callback function that is called at the end of each
>   chunkInterval. Typically used to implement a progress indicator, e.g.
>   code in RealWorld 50k. Defaults to `null`. Arguments: Number of
>   processed markers Total number of markers being added Elapsed time (in
>   ms)

the `chunkProgress` function should have all necessary information. In particular the structure of the progress bar would be call would be:

```
incProgress(Number of processed markers / Total number of markers, 
            detail = paste("Doing point", Number of processed markers))
```

***How can I access those values and make them available for the `incProgress` call and ensure that `incProgress` is called repeatedly during the map plotting?***

---

## Side notes

Leaflet offers bespoke [plugins](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/68064/45300) facilitating displaying of progress loading indicators. I'm *only* interested in a solution that would utilise Shiny's "native" mechanism of showing the progress bar as in the actual map I've other functions updating the progress bar.

Comment: @akrun That object corresponds to leaflet's background maps. The example is modelled on the original leaflet example and it should work.

Comment: I have `leaflet_1.0.1`.  Is that your version

Comment: @akrun You are right, I tried example on a different PC with `leaflet_1.0.1` and it  did not work returning the same error, same with the [official example](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html). The current version of leaflet is **1.1.0** so I reckon that the previous version did not return `providers` object into the app environment. If you choose to upgrade, the provided example should work.

Comment: It looks like the R's leaflet package uses marker cluster v0.5 (based on the javascript loaded in the head). `chunkLoading` was introduced in v1.0 of marker cluster.

Comment: @NicE Thanks for taking the time to look into this; I reckon that that's a major blocker but I'll leave the question hanging in case some will come with some ingenious way to address this problem.